# Scrape ONLY a certain <div> using gocolly

Tags: go, go-colly

I'm trying to make a web scraper using gocolly. I want to ONLY scrape a `<div>` element with the id of `dailyText` on `https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/h/r1/lp-e`. How can I do this?

Comment: Check out [this example](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/blob/master/_examples/basic/basic.go) and replace the selector in `c.OnHTML("a[href]"...` with `div#dailyText`, then adapt the function accordingly. If it's not entirely clear feel free to ask more questions or check out the [other examples](https://github.com/gocolly/colly/tree/master/_examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to xarantolus for this answer.
This worked great for me (if the domain allowed me to use it, that is.)

```
func main() {
    cly := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("https://yourpage.site"),
    )
    cly.OnHTML("body", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("div")
        fmt.Printf("Link found: %q -> %s\n", e.Text, link)
        cly.Visit(e.Request.AbsoluteURL(link))
    })
    cly.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())
    })
    page := cly.Visit("https://yourpage.site")
    fmt.Print(page)
}
```